# Helix Toolkit WPF Removal of Default Blue Gray internal external colors C#

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

Like many who have used Helix Toolkit for importing models I get the dreaded default Blue and gray (internal and external colors respectively) displayed. Common answers state that it is because of naming convention mismatch between the .obj and .mtl however this is not strictly true.

After investigating it appears that the .mtl of a .obj is applied correctly as glossiness of the material shows through and changes the material to a lighter gray. I suspect that it is pulling the same gray that the cad software uses as they look the same unlike the darker default gray (my material is a gold metal PBR for an .obj and .mat file that shares the same names inside and out and appear to be called).

Items were prepared in Blender and Substance designer. Interestingly If applying a neon green diffuse color to a cube in blender and export, when imported the cube would look a light green as though the software was mixing the default gray color together.

Ideally I want a realistic metal PBR material Programmatically added to the viewport without XAML in C#. I have merged vertices in Blender and it appears that this does not change the outcome.

Is there a way of;
1. Changing the order programmatically in C# the default colors and .mtl file is called so that it is on top? Or
2. Removing the default colors all together programmatically and using the .mtl in its place
3. Changing opacity of the default colors programmatically.
N.B. Files appear to be named correctly and copied into the /bin/debug folder as well as being 'added' to the solution window.
N.B. Lighting is default.
N.B. Why is the gray showing on the outside of the model when a material is applied, replacing the blue?
N.B. Have only tried importing .stl and .obj, if another file format does not have this issue open to suggestion. .Obj selected as it was similar to .stl however gave a smoother surface.

Any ideas here would be much appreciated. IF there is no way forward with this what other 3D 'api' could I use to replace this that has better documentation yet same functionality.

Comment: which version of Helix are you using? The WPF or WPF.SharpDX version? The importers in the WPF version definitely have problems (and from what I can see are not going to be updated as the assimp importers seem to be the preferred route).

Comment: Hi, I am using Helix V2.12.0 and WPF.SharpDX at V2.12.0. When you say assimp importers what are these?

Comment: There are two sets of importers unfortunately. The more robust one uses a third party library called Assimp. You use it as follows... HelixToolkit.SharpDX.Core.Assimp.Importer importer = new HelixToolkit.SharpDX.Core.Assimp.Importer();
var scene = importer.Load(objPath);

Comment: The older importer (and from what I can see less robust and less supported) is used as follows... StudioReader objReader = new StudioReader();
var model = objReader.Read(objPath);

Comment: Hi, I have tried the suggestions above however it has not provided much luck. I am thinking that I may need to change to a newer 3D method such as learning Vulcan or something else (any thoughts welcome). At present current learning is from scrambling around on the internet and the present support.. There must be a better way to embed 3D graphics effectively in a WPF .NET framework  without having to go closer to the hardware or scavenge for a suitable procedure.